# Android Eclipse- Downloading an image from a URL to storage on phone

Tags: android, eclipse, image, download, android-asynctask

So I've been looking around for an explanation on how to download a URL image (.png) to the phone itself-

I have a method going off on a menu select once they choose the photo- and it sends over the URL path as well as the filename i would like it to be called(test.png for the time being)

I am trying to do this AsynC as well to keep the UI free-

The code below actually goes off fine, but it doesn't seem to save any image though-
(I don't have an SD card on my phone, but I tried saving to the data folder for testing as well, with same results)

```
protected void saveImage(String imageUrl, String fileName){  
    class SendPostReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
        private String imageUrl;
        private String fileName;
        public SendPostReqAsyncTask (String imageUrl, String fileName)
        {   
            super();
            this.imageUrl=imageUrl;
            this.fileName=fileName;
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String newfilename="";
            try {
                File externalStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                URL urlTmp = new URL(imageUrl);
                newfilename = urlTmp.getFile();
                newfilename = externalStorageDirectory + "/" + fileName;
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(urlTmp.openStream());
                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(newfilename);
                if (bitmap != null) {
                    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 50, fileOutputStream);
                    return newfilename;
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                Log.w("errorSaving", "Could not save image with url: " + imageUrl, e);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.w("errorSaving", "Could not save image with url: " + imageUrl, e);
            }
            Log.d("errorSaving", "Failed to save image " + fileName);

            return newfilename;
        }

        //handle result when done
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Photo saved to phone: " + result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    SendPostReqAsyncTask sendPostReqAsyncTask = new SendPostReqAsyncTask(imageUrl,fileName);
    sendPostReqAsyncTask.execute();     
}
```

Comment: Standard Question: Do you have permission to write to external storage? If yes, do you have permission to access the internet? If yes, please explain where your code fails.

Comment: yes I have permissions set in the manifest, unfortunately im not getting any errors- the code runs, but it just doesn't actually save any file

Comment: Walk through your code line-by-line. You're not getting errors if you're just throwing warnings (Log.w) anyway. The first newFilename assignment is superfluous. It's something obvious, like an incorrect url or a missing fileName.

Answer (score 0):

```
//To download image from a url
Drawable image;
try {
    InputStream is          = (InputStream) this.fetch(your_image_url);
    image                   = Drawable.createFromStream(is,"src");
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

//Convert drawable to Bitmap
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image).getBitmap();

//Save Bitmap to a file
try {image
       FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
       bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
} catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Also make sure that you set the internet permission in manifest file,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: unfortunatelt the Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image).getBitmap(); as well as the this.fetch method cannot be resolved